# Header changes opacity when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have my header change opacity when you scroll down say **aproximatly 500px down**. I'm making a single page with a header infront of a bxslider so when I scroll down the opacity should increase for the header because the text still needs to be readable.

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

I'd like something like this but I find it very hard to edit

I already tried to look for answers here but only thing close to this is: [Header changes as you scroll down (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687580/header-changes-as-you-scroll-down-jquery) or [Fade opacity when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653543/fade-opacity-when-scrolling) but the one doesn't work for me and the other is to hard to understand and change

```
<header class="main-header">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
        <nav>
            <a id="active" href="#Platenbeurs">Platenbeurs</a>
            <a href="#Voorstelling">Voorstelling</a>
            <a href="#Planning">Planning</a>
            <a href="#Grondplan">Grondplan</a>
            <a href="#PraktischeInfo">Praktische Info</a>
            <a href="#Bestel">Bestel</a>
        </nav>
</header>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the css code to see that the header is actualy not opacity 1.

```
.main-header{ position: fixed; max-width: 1024px; width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 1%; text-align: right; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); border-top: 5px solid black; border-bottom: 5px solid black; }
.main-header nav a{ color: white; text-decoration: none; opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fixed it myself...

HTML

```
<header class="main-header clearfix">
    <a href="#Top"><img src="images/logo.svg"/></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#Platenbeurs">Platenbeurs</a>
        <a href="#voorstelling">Voorstelling</a>
        <a href="#artiesten">Artiesten</a>
        <a href="#Planning">Planning</a>
        <a href="#Grondplan">Grondplan</a>
        <a href="#PraktischeInfo">Praktische Info</a>
        <a href="#Bestel">Bestel</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.main-header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}
.main-header nav a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){

        if($(document).scrollTop() > 300){
            if(header.data('opacity') == 'start'){
                header.data('opacity','scrolled');
                header.css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,1)");
            }
        }else{
            if(header.data('opacity') == 'scrolled'){
                header.data('opacity','start');
                header.css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The opacity off the header is already `1`. You can't increase the opacity, instead you can set the background color for header on scroll. Please refer the following snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/uy25hw21/

Comment: I added the css for you, so you can see the header isn't opacity 1